# Glue to Secure Dishwasher to Granite

Tags: dishwasher, adhesive, granite

Recently my dishwasher (DW) required service which meant pulling it out from under the granite counter top. The DW was secured to the counter top with two metal tabs which were glued to the counter top. The DW is operational again but I am searching for the type of glue that was used. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

[image]

**Edit:**

The epoxy product I ended up using is called *Loctite Epoxy Five Minute Instant Mix*. Before applying it, I used sand paper to remove the old epoxy. Then I simply applied the epoxy to the metal tabs, slid the dishwasher back into place with the door open, and clamped the metal tabs to the counter top. The next morning, I removed the clamps and verified the epoxy was rock solid. Rock on!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two Part [Epoxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoxy).

But I wouldn't use it to hold the clip in; I'd use it to attach a [tee nut](https://www.google.com/search?q=tee%20nut&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGiLuFgujPAhWGWx4KHdZtBtIQ_AUICSgC&biw=1024&bih=639), which is then fastened with a bolt to the clips on the dishwasher, facilitating removal or replacement in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There are devices called Granite Grabbers, which come with adhesive strips, which are designed to fix to granite worktops. Many dishwasher manufacturers also sell a Solid Surface Undercabinet Mounting Kit, which will work.

An alternative with a lot of dishwashers is to not fix them to the granite worktop, but to secure through the sides to the adjoining cabinets.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to write an answer to an old question because I have done a lot of granite and dishwashers...

Clear Silicone.   That's it.   These tabs aren't to set the dish washer in place, they are tip guards.   You don't make it permanent with an epoxy or the first time you pull your dishwasher out you will be messing up the granite.

Comment: Better yet, don't attach the dishwasher directly to the granite, lower it slightly and use a batten strip attached to the walls.  I used a plastic finished part matching the cabinet trim.

Answer (score 0):

Use a granite grabber mount system (e.g., Smart Choice dishwasher mounting kit). Each mount has an adhesive strip and built in nuts to screw the dishwasher tabs into.  After clamping for several hours, remove the clamps. These usually last a couple years or more, but to make them permanent, add some epoxy (e.g., JB Weld) to the mount edges and the granite, overlapping the mounts. That will be a permanent mount that you can use with future replacement dishwashers. Silicone glue could also work as a second best option.